# Simplify to the specific form

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, factorization

I want to simply expression into specific form that I want to have. For example,

$e^{-v^2}\frac{ (a*v-b)}{c*v^2-d*v+e}$

```
(-b + a v)/(e - d v + c v^2) Exp[-v^2]
```

I want to factor this and make a form as

$A*e^{-v^2} * \frac{ (v-\text{a1})}{(v-b1) (v-\text{b2})}$

```
A ((v - a1) Exp[-v^2])/((v -b1) (v-b2))
```

Of course, I can just do it manually one by one, solve the numerator, find root etc. Does MMA have any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SolveAlways` to obtain relations between `{A, a1, b1, b2}` and `{a, b, c, d, e}` for arbitrary `v` and then apply `Solve` to those relations to express the new coefficients in terms of the old.

```
SolveAlways[(-b + a v)/(e - d v + c v^2) Exp[-v^2] == 
    A ((v - a1) Exp[-v^2])/((v - b1) (v - b2)), v];
Flatten[Solve[#, {A, a1, b1, b2}] & /@ (% /. Rule -> Equal), 1]
(* {{A -> a/c, a1 -> b/a, 
     b1 -> (d - Sqrt[d^2 - 4 c e])/(2 c), b2 -> (d + Sqrt[d^2 - 4 c e])/(2 c)}, 
    {A -> a/c, a1 -> b/a, 
     b1 -> (d + Sqrt[d^2 - 4 c e])/(2 c), b2 -> (d - Sqrt[d^2 - 4 c e])/(2 c)}} *)
```

The two sets of relations differ only by interchanging the definitions of `b1` and `b2`. as expected.  No knowledge of the details of the expressions is needed, provided that the expressions are not too complicated for `SolveAlways` to handle.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way

```
(E^-v^2 (-b + a v))/(
 e - d v + c v^2) /. {(-b + a v) -> a (v - sol1[[1, 1, 2]]), 
  e - d v + c v^2 -> (v - sol2[[1, 1, 2]]) (v - sol2[[2, 1, 2]])}
```

which gives

```
(a E^-v^2 (-(b/a) + v))/((-((d - Sqrt[d^2 - 4 c e])/(2 c)) + 
   v) (-((d + Sqrt[d^2 - 4 c e])/(2 c)) + v))
```

Comment: [Really?](https://imgur.com/a/9Ro2s)

Comment: corey979 I was not aware of SolveAlways

Comment: I say that your code doesn't give the output you claim. And what are `sol1` and `sol2`? They don't appear in the OP. As it stands, this does not answer the question.

Comment: Corey Sorry I have forgotten the definition of sol1 and sol2. I have made an edit